# Spring-data-aerospike cannot set field to null

Tags: java, spring-data, repository-pattern, aerospike

Suppose you have a document:

```
@Document(collection = "person-document", touchOnRead = true)
public class PersonDocument {

    @Id
    long id;

    @Field
    String transaction;
}
```

That's how you're creating the entity:

```
PersonDocument person = new PersonDocument(1L, "112e-dfsc-3442-cwce-3434");
repository.save(person);
```

That's how you're trying to update the entity:

```
PersonDocument person = repository.findOne(1L);
person.setTransaction(null);
repository.save(person);
```

However the latter does not delete the bin value for 'transaction' and the value "112e-dfsc-3442-cwce-3434" still exists in the datastore.

The workaround for this - update the value with empty string, however it's a bit confusing, considering the way how other implementations of spring data work (particularly spring-data-jpa).

Isn't it better to remove bin value if entity field is set to `NULL` instead of keep the old value? Because for now `NULL` properties are discarded during update.

Answer (score 1):

Please, consider using latest version of [spring-data-aerospike](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aerospike/spring-data-aerospike/1.2.1.RELEASE).

This should not be an issue, I've just checked the scenario works correctly.
If you still see an issue -- please open ticket and provide a test case.